# EF Core 7: BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync overrides default constraint values with incorrect values

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have created a table with a default constraint defined using code first something like this for Azure SQL:

```
    builder.Property(c => c.CreatedDate)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasDefaultValueSql("sysdatetimeoffset()");
```

When I use `BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync()` to UPSERT the record, I see that value is set as 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00 instead of the default constraint value during INSERT. How can I enable the value from default constraint for INSERT and prevent overwritten for UPDATE?

Comment: That's not a native EF function.  So please specify and add a tag for where you got it.

Comment: EFCore.BulkExtensions 7.0.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can this by Properties Exclude in BulkConfig:
this is config

```
var bulkConfig = new BulkConfig()
    {  PropertiesToExclude = new List<string> {  nameof(Class.Column) } };
```

Example Config

```
var bulkConfig = new BulkConfig()
    {

        PropertiesToExclude = new List<string> {  nameof(Blog.created) }

    };
```

You can create code base  with the following statements:

```
create Class
--
public partial class Blog
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }

        public string title { get; set; }

    }
}

Change OnModelCreating
--

 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().Property(e => e.created).HasDefaultValueSql("(sysdatetimeoffset())").ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();

        }


Insert Data into Blog  with BulkInsertAsync
--
var bulkConfig = new BulkConfig()
    {

        PropertiesToExclude = new List<string> {  nameof(Blog.created) }

    };
    var subEntities = new List<Blog>();
    var maths1 = new Blog() { title = "Maths1" };
    subEntities.Add(maths1);

    maths1 = new Blog() { title = "Maths2" };
    subEntities.Add(maths1);

   
    await context.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(subEntities, bulkConfig);
```